# Client ip logging on the server running with load balancer

Tags: apache

The server with my website has started working with load balancer.

Previous log format

> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"" combined

this format now contains the IP Address of the load balancer

I found the following solution to this problem on the php side

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IPS"]
```

Is there a solution to this problem in log formats?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the correct flag in the custom log format: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html
Also consider using X-Forwarded-For header: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239